# Map redux dispatch to redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I'm a Redux beginner, and I couldn't find anything related.

I'm having trouble mapping dispatch to ReduxForm. Im setting up my reducers like this:

```js
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import foo from './foo';
import bar from './bar';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  foo,
  bar,
  form: formReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and then combining them like so:

```
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

const createStoreWithMiddlware = applyMiddleware(
   thunkMiddleware,
  loggerMiddleware
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStoreWithMiddlware(rootReducer, initialState);
  return store;
}
```

and then mapping dispatch to props like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    foo: state.foo,
    bar: state.bar
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch),
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

And then I have a form component that I am wrapping in a reduxForm like this:

```
TestForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'testForm',
  fields: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email']
})(TestForm);

export default TestForm;
```

But I get an error:

```
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop dispatch was not specified in ReduxForm(TestForm). Check the render method of TestFormParent.
```

What is the best way to inject dispatch into a form component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the docs on npm are a little bit different, and more complete. If anyone else runs into this issue, use connectReduxForm instead of reduxForm solved the problem.

Comment: This was true during the v3-beta period. Rectified now.

Comment: If this solved your problem you should accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

reduxForm works for version 4 of redux-form